# facing issues while replacing string.replace() with values

Tags: string

i've xml coming as string as show below:

```
<Product type= "item"><values>123</values><values>123</values><Product type="desc"><values>123</values><values>123</values></Product><Product type= "item"><values>123</values><values>123</values></Product>
```

and am expecting output as

```
<Product type= "item"><values>123</values><values>123</values><Product type="desc"><values>123</values><values>123</values></Product></Product><Product type= "item"><values>123</values><values>123</values></Product>
```

i want to replace `</Product>` end tag as `</Product></Product>` only in case if there is inner start product tag for desc otherwise i wanna to keep only one `</Product>`

Please let me know any suggestion on this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Instr function to find require strings

```
yourstr="<Product type= "item"><values>123</values><values>123</values> <Product type="desc"><values>123</values><values>123</values></Product>" 

 If (InStr(yourstr, '<Product type= "item">') > 0) and (InStr(yourstr, '<Product type= "desc">') > 0)Then

//do replace stuff here

End If
```

It just an idea to to solve this problem, the actual code may be differ based upon your programming language.

Comment: but my string will be dynamic containing multiple <Products type='Item'> with or without <Product type='desc'>, and also the sequence is random

Comment: If it is too much complicated then you are advised to use Regex Replace method.